# How to add sortable cell to table row where is no other sortable items?

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

Trying to make table with sortable cells using JQuery. Issue im faced with is when in row no more sortable cells it is not possible to move cell into it. Im was tryed to add invisible sortable cell (to first row) but it`s not helped.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled"></td>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">a</td>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">1</td>
      <td>First row: 1</td>
      <td>First row: 2</td>
      <td class=" cell-placeholder">holder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">2</td>
      <td>
        <button>
          Second row: 1
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="text" value="Second row: 2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


$("table tbody ").sortable({
  items: 'td:not(.ui-state-disabled)',
  cancel: ".disabled",
  revert: true
}).disableSelection();

td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: dotted 1px black;
}

.cell-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergei_m/m29r3aqa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the sortable on the **rows** elements and use `connectWith`.

```js
$("table tbody tr").sortable({
   items: 'td:not(.ui-state-disabled)',
   connectWith: "table tbody tr",
   cancel: ".disabled",
revert: true
 }).disableSelection();
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: dotted 1px black;
}

.cell-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled"></td>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">a</td>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">1</td>
      <td>First row: 1</td>
      <td>First row: 2</td>
      <td class=" cell-placeholder">holder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-disabled">2</td>
      <td>
        <button>
          Second row: 1
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="text" value="Second row: 2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this can also help for diabling rows. thanks for this